# Python List Comprehension - Accessing Index

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How would I go about converting this into a list comprehension?

```
queue_lengths = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for i, queue in enumerate(queue_lengths):
    if queue > 0:
        queue_lengths[i] = queue - 1
```

Below obviously won't work, because we don't have access to i.

```
queue_lengths[i] = [(queue - 1) for i, queue in enumerate(queue_lengths) if queue > 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just needed more time.

```
queue_lengths = [(queue - 1) if queue > 0 else queue for queue in queue_lengths]
```